# Unable to catch null data properly from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to catch all data from MySQL to check data already exists or not
if data already exists then it should update else insert new data.
I have 7 to 8 conditions in where clause, some of them are null
now the issue is
when i run query its not catching null column thats why its insert new data instead of updating
below is my code

```
$fetch_stock = mysqli_query($connection, 
        "SELECT * 
        FROM `book_stock` 
        WHERE book_name = '$book_name' 
        AND author_id = $book_author 
        AND author_id1 = $book_author1 
        AND author_id2 = $book_author2 
        AND author_id3 = $book_author3 
        AND author_id4 = $book_author4 
        AND author_id5 = $book_author5 
        AND author_id6 = $book_author6"
    );

if (mysqli_num_rows($fetch_stock) > 0) {
    echo "UPDATE book_stock SET stock_count = stock_count + 1 WHERE book_name = '$book_name' AND author_id = $book_author AND author_id1 = $book_author1 AND author_id2 = $book_author2 AND author_id3 = $book_author3 AND author_id4 = $book_author4 AND author_id5 = $book_author5 AND author_id6 = $book_author6";
    mysqli_query($connection, 
            "UPDATE book_stock 
                SET stock_count = stock_count + 1 
            WHERE book_name = '$book_name' 
            AND author_id = $book_author 
            AND author_id1 = $book_author1 
            AND author_id2 = $book_author2 
            AND author_id3 = $book_author3 
            AND author_id4 = $book_author4 
            AND author_id5 = $book_author5 
            AND author_id6 = $book_author6"
        );
} else {
    echo "INSERT INTO book_stock (book_name, author_id, author_id1, author_id2, author_id3, author_id4, author_id5, author_id6, stock_count) value ('$book_name', $book_author,$book_author1, $book_author2, $book_author3, $book_author4, $book_author5, $book_author6, 1)";

    mysqli_query($connection, 
            "INSERT INTO book_stock 
                    (book_name, author_id, author_id1, author_id2, 
                    author_id3, author_id4, author_id5, author_id6, 
                    stock_count) 
            value ('$book_name', $book_author,$book_author1, $book_author2, 
                    $book_author3, $book_author4, $book_author5, $book_author6, 1)");

}
```

When i print query Its look like this

```
INSERT INTO book_stock 
        (book_name, author_id, author_id1, author_id2, author_id3, 
        author_id4, author_id5, author_id6, stock_count) 
    value ('cat demo1', 1,2, 3, 4, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1)
```

I got solution for this from 1 website, which is

```
$fetch_stock = mysqli_query($connection, 
        "SELECT * 
        FROM `book_stock` 
        WHERE book_name = '$book_name' 
        AND author_id = $book_author 
        AND IFNULL(author_id1, 0)= IFNULL($book_author1, 0) 
        AND IFNULL(author_id2, 0)= IFNULL($book_author2, 0) 
        AND IFNULL(author_id3, 0)= IFNULL($book_author3, 0) 
        AND IFNULL(author_id4, 0)= IFNULL($book_author4, 0) 
        AND IFNULL(author_id5, 0) = IFNULL($book_author5, 0) 
        AND IFNULL(author_id6, 0) = IFNULL($book_author6, 0)"
    );
```

Its working when i want to display stock.

But i want to do a crud operation by using this logic.

I tried to do from above solution, its work fine but, in db table its update null with 0.

which is not got as per me.
please guide me with best solution.

Thanks

Comment: It feels like you've got a deeper problem with the actual structure of the database; there _should_ be a `book` table and an `author` table with a link table to join them together at the very least, it's a many-to-many relationship... but you also need a way to actually identify *exactly* which book you're referring to when you're looking at the stock; is it the hardback or paperback version, which edition is it? You might want to use the ISBN for a unique identifier, for instance. I think you need to rethink the underlying database structure really.